# How to make sure my object list of users follows the Columns list of a react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, html-table, jsx

Hi everyone, I'd like to talk to you about what I'm trying to do. In short, I created an HTML table using React by dividing the Table.js into itself with two components such as:
StaffColumns.js
StaffData.js
Inside these two we have functions with passed props that is:

StaffData.js

```
//utentiLista it's my list of objects inside an Array called "utentiLista"
const StaffDati = ({utentiLista}) => {
    
  const styleText = {
    backgroundColor: '#1F2A37',
    textAlign: 'left',
    padding:'10px 10px 10px 10px',
    color: 'var(--primary-text)',
    paddingLeft: '10px',
    borderTop: '1px solid #343E4E',
    borderBottom: '1px solid #343E4E',
  }


    const getStatusStyle = (status) => {
        switch (status) {
          case 'Completed':
            return ({ color: 'lightgreen',
                      src: check
            });
          case 'Pending':
            return { color: 'yellow',
                      src: hour
          };
          case 'In progress':
            return { color: '#A992F6',
                      src: cloud
          };
          default:
            return {};
        }
      };
      
    return (
        <tbody style={{width:'100%'}}>
      {//! la lista utenti viene passata come props a Tabella e poi fatto un mapping proprio come in Sidebar.js
      
      utentiLista.map((utente, index) => (
        
      <tr key={utente.id} style={{width:'100%'}}>
        <td style={{...styleText, borderLeft: index === -1  ? 'none' : '1px solid #343E4E'}}>{utente.id}</td>
        <td style={styleText}>{utente.username}</td>
        <td style={styleText}>{utente.data}</td>
        <td style={styleText}>{utente.amount}€</td>
        <td style={{...styleText, borderRight: index === utentiLista.length  ? 'none' : '1px solid #343E4E' }}>

          <div style={{color: getStatusStyle(utente.status).color, 
                       width: 'fit-content', 
                       padding:'5px', 
                       border:`1px solid ${getStatusStyle(utente.status).color}`, 
                       borderRadius: '10px', 
                       fontSize: '10px',
                       backgroundColor: '#374151',
                       display: 'flex',
                       flexDirection: 'row', 
                       flexWrap: 'no-wrap',
                       alignContent: 'center', 
                       gap: '5px'}}>
                        <img src={getStatusStyle(utente.status).src} alt="" />
          {utente.status}
          </div>
          </td>
      
      </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
    )
    
}

export default StaffDati;
```

My StaffColumns instead have this code:

```
import React, {useState, useTransition } from "react"
const ColoneStaff = ({utentiLista, setUtentiLista}) => {
    
    const styleTr = {
        backgroundColor: '#374151',
        color: 'var(--primary-text)',
        textAlign: 'left',
      }
      const styleTh = {
        backgroundColor: '#374151',
        color: 'var(--primary-text)',
        textAlign: 'left',
        padding: '20px 0px 20px 10px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
      };
      const [staffColumns, setStaffColumns] = useState([
        {
        name: 'ID',
        field: 'id',
        type: 'number',
        style: styleTh,
        ascending: true,
        isSortable: true,
      },
      {
          name: 'Username',
          field: 'username',
          type: 'string',
          style: styleTh,
          ascending: true,
          isSortable: true,
      },
      {
          name: 'Data',
          field: 'data',
          type: 'string',
          style: styleTh,
          ascending: true,
          isSortable: false,
      },
      {
          name: 'Amount',
          field: 'amount',
          type: 'number',
          style: styleTh,
          ascending: true,
          isSortable: true,
      },
      {
          name: 'Status',
          field: 'status',
          type: 'string',
          style: styleTh,
          ascending: true,
          isSortable: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'Action',
        field: 'action',
        type: 'string',
        style: styleTh,
        ascending: true,
        isSortable: false,
      }
      
    ]);
    const handleSort = (field) => {
      const sortingColumn = staffColumns.find((column) => column.field === field);
      if (field) {
        const updatedColumns = staffColumns.map((column) => {
          if (column.field === field && column.isSortable) {
            column.ascending = !column.ascending;
          }
          return column;
        });
  
        setStaffColumns(updatedColumns);
  
        const sortedList = [...utentiLista].sort((a, b) => {
          const aValue = a[field];
          const bValue = b[field];
          if(sortingColumn.type === 'number'){
          return sortingColumn.ascending ? aValue - bValue : bValue - aValue;
        }else{
          return sortingColumn.ascending
            ? String(aValue).localeCompare(String(bValue))
            : String(bValue).localeCompare(String(aValue));
        }
        });
        setUtentiLista(sortedList);
      }
    };

    return (
        <thead>
 <tr style={{...styleTr}}>

        {staffColumns.map((column) =>  {
            return(
             <th key={column.field} onClick={() =>handleSort(column.field)} style={column.style}>
             {column.name}
            </th>  
            )
        })
    }
     </tr>
    </thead>
    )
}
export default ColoneStaff;
```

Now my question it's pretty simple, how can I check if my `utentiLista.keys` are equal to my  StaffColumns list. Inside StaffColumns I created an object that has no properties of the usersList object and therefore does not print anything in the table data but simply prints the empty Column. This is the `{name:'Action'}` object.
I would like to be able to find the "intruder" object in my columnStaff list, and not delete it but every time a column like that of 'Action' is added and which does not correspond to any value of the usersList object, and which then go and print a simple "in the data of that column Action".
`<td>Missing Value</td>`
This is my usersList array:

```
  const [utentiLista, setUtentiLista] = useState([
    {id: 1, username: 'FEDERICOSCHI', data: '...', amount: 2000, status: 'Completed'},
    {id: 2, username: 'Feryzz', data: '...', amount: 15, status: 'Completed'},
    {id: 3, username: 'Cinquanta', data: '...', amount: 27, status: 'Pending'},
    {id: 4, username: 'NotAffected', data: '...', amount: 50, status: 'In progress'},
    {id: 5, username: 'Ytnoos', data: '...', amount: 12, status: 'Completed'},
    {id: 6, username: 'Mattia882', data: '...', amount: 33, status: 'In progress'}
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that your utentiLista (users list) aligns with the columns defined in your StaffColumns component, you can add a check in your StaffData component. The idea is to iterate over the columns and dynamically create table data () elements based on whether the corresponding property exists in each user object.

Here's a quick way to do it:

Pass staffColumns to StaffDati: First, you'll need to pass your columns state (staffColumns) from ColoneStaff to StaffDati as a prop. This will give StaffDati the information it needs about which columns should be displayed.

Create  Elements Based on Columns: In StaffDati, iterate over staffColumns to create your  elements. For each column, check if the corresponding property exists in the user object. If it does, display the value; if not, display a placeholder like "Missing Value".

```
const StaffDati = ({ utentiLista, staffColumns }) => {
    // ... existing code ...

    return (
        <tbody style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            {utentiLista.map((utente) => (
                <tr key={utente.id} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                    {staffColumns.map((column) => {
                        // Check if the user object has the property corresponding to the column
                        if (utente.hasOwnProperty(column.field)) {
                            return <td style={styleText}>{utente[column.field]}</td>;
                        } else {
                            // If the property doesn't exist, display a placeholder
                            return <td style={styleText}>Missing Value</td>;
                        }
                    })}
                </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
    );
};

export default StaffDati;
```

This approach will dynamically align your user data with the columns. If you add a new column that doesn't have a corresponding property in the user objects, it will automatically display "Missing Value" (or whatever placeholder you choose) in that column's cells.

Hope this helps you out! Let me know if you have any more questions.